# Injected DAO is null

Tags: java, ejb

To keep it short, the injected DAO is null. This is the code:

IssueBeanLocal is annotated with @Local and the persistence unit name is name="fmiunibuc"

```
@Stateless
public class IssueBean implements IssueBeanLocal{
    @Inject IssueDAO issueDAO;

    @Override
    public List<Object[]> loadDDL(String table) {
        return issueDAO.getDDL(table);
    }
}
```

The DAO:

```
public class IssueDAO extends GenericDAO {

public Issue getById(Long id) {
    Issue issue = findById(id, Issue.class);
    if (issue == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No theme design validation exists with ID [" + id + "].");
    }
    return issue;
}

public List<Object[]> getDDL(String tableName) {

    List<Object[]> returnList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    StringBuilder dynamicQuery = new StringBuilder();

    dynamicQuery.append(" SELECT cat.id ");
    dynamicQuery.append(",  cat.code + ' ' + cat.name as ddlValue");
    dynamicQuery.append(" FROM ").append(tableName + " as cat ");
    dynamicQuery.append(" WHERE cat.active = true");

    dynamicQuery.append(" order by cat.code");
    returnList = entityManager.createQuery(dynamicQuery.toString(), Object[].class).getResultList();

    //returnList
    return returnList;
}
```

GenericDAO:

```
public abstract class GenericDAO {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName="fmiunibuc", type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
  protected EntityManager entityManager;

  protected static Logger logger;

  public GenericDAO() {
       logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
  }

  public <T> void persist(T entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
  }
      // some other methods
}
```

When the execution reaches "issueDAO.getDDL(table);" the issueDAO is null.
Keep in mind that I'm new to java programming, so please be as explicit as you can.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share with us your project structure? Did you enable CDI on your project?

Comment: Create an empty bean.xml and try again

Comment: CDI is enable. But when i created the bean.xml the error changed to this:  No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fmiunibuc. Thank you, I will try to handle it from here